# How to downcast sample rate of ndarray (without saving it as wav file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

I have a `ndarray` (which I got from microphone) with samples (sample rate = 48000).

I want to create a new `ndarray` with lower sample rate (16000).

One option is to save this `ndarray` as `wav` file and reload it with different sample rate (via `librosa`).

Is there a simple way to do it without saving the `ndarray` as wav file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a method resample in `librosa` and you can use it without saving the file

```
import librosa
original_data, sr = librosa.load('0 .wav', sr=None)
print(original_data.shape)
resampled_data = librosa.resample(original_data, orig_sr=sr, target_sr=16000)
print(resampled_data.shape)
```